# PackageManager install-package change default folder

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to change the default folder to which package manager installs jquery scripts to say folder by the name JavaScript instead of the Scripts folder in a MVC project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the package author needs to provide us this feature. 
Source - 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1885579.aspx/1?PackageManager+install+package+change+default+folder